# Modeling and Predicting Co-Occuring Values

Tags: predictive-modeling

I have data for a 100,000 people with different personality traits. Here would be sample data:

```
Person  Trait-1   Trait-2   Trait-3 .....   Trait-N
John     1          0         1                1
```

I need a model where for a new user when I see Trait-X, I need a prediction of the likelihood of all other Traits i.e. how likely is he to have any of the other traits. Can someone point me to a possible model I could use? I am a novice so don't know much about this space.

Comment: Welcome to DataScience.SE! I hope you find it useful. Do you have a social graph relating the new user to existing users? Are all the traits binary? Do you have any other metadata about the users?

Comment: Thanks! all the traits are unfortunately binary and there is no relation listed between the existing users or new ones. The source as I understand was from online surveys where people participated from across the world. Their answers determined the assigned traits and this is the only data I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend a [Restricted Boltzmann machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restricted_Boltzmann_machine), which is a type of neural network that can model probability distributions. What you are trying to do is to estimate the [marginal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marginal_distribution) of the [missing features](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Missing_data). In a probabilistic model, this is done through *marginalization*. The beauty of this method is that it provides the full distribution over the missing features rather than mere [point estimates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_estimation).

[Here](http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/rbm.html) [are](http://blog.echen.me/2011/07/18/introduction-to-restricted-boltzmann-machines/) two tutorials.